# What happens to Attached Volumes during AWS EC2 Auto Recovery Activity?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

During the event of AWS EC2 Auto Recovery, the documentation quotes that it retains the IP, Instance ID, and other details; there isn't full info about how the volumes would behave. Would also bring the same volume with Volume mapping to the newly recovered instances ?

Is there a way we can manually test or try to understand the behavior - like trying to intentionally trigger the failed check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page on the AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-recovery-for-amazon-ec2/):

"With this week’s launch, you can now arrange for automatic recovery of an EC2 instance when a system status check of the underlying hardware fails. The instance will be rebooted (on new hardware if necessary) but will retain its Instance Id, IP Address, Elastic IP Addresses, **EBS Volume attachments**, and other configuration details. In order for the recovery to be complete, you’ll need to make sure that the instance automatically starts up any services or applications as part of its initialization process."

So EBS volumes are mapped on the new instance. I doubt instance store volumes have their data copied over to the new instance - AWS are quite clear that they're temporary storage.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to test the setup. Like manually fail the instance to perform auto recovery ?

Comment: No, it's only for hardware failure. Reboot your instance to check your services all come up properly, and keep regular snapshots matching your RPO in case automatic recovery doesn't work.